# Generate And Print a Microsoft Word document from Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office

I'm looking for some library that lets me create a document with a particular format an then print it.
At First i used Microsoft.Office.Interop, but my boss said that the server is not going to have office installed.
So I'm looking for some free library that lets me create the document and print it...

edit: i forgot to say its a .doc or docx, but i don't need to save it, only print without using ActiveX.

Comment: "create a document with a particular format" is a pretty vague requirement. What is the "particular format"?

Comment: What kind of documents are you trying to create?

Comment: its a legal document, with a margin and text format like bold and italics. i forgot to say that i need a word document

Comment: @Shiny: do the documents already exist? Where? A database?

Comment: @Shiny: also, if you need to create the document, but not save it, then why does it need to be a Microsoft Word document?

Comment: Its because my boss said: "You should keep the data from the vbscript" technically I 
can change the code, as long as i keep the margins and headers, he will never know. but i preffer to obey since im on my first 
week of work. The vbscript uses activeX to print, so the user MUST have 
Office installed or the code won't run. I pointed that was poorly coded and it was not 
compatible. So i need to use a library that let me pass the format from the Word document already done.
Maybe i need to print without creating the Word document. but as i need to keep the format i don't know which library use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Microsoft Office 2003+ documents, have a look at the Open XML SDK. This allows you to manipulate / create .docx etc. document.

Alternatively, if you are using SQL Server Reporting Services, this provides a web service that will allow you to generate a report as a PDF programmatically.

Comment: after a lot of tries i reached what i wanted with this library, tnx DaveRead ^^

Answer (score 1):

We use [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx) at my company.  It works quite well, and can make different types of documents.  It is a little bit tedious to learn to use, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ to create PDF from HTML files. Documents are pretty and easy to print.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but I've heard good things about [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).

Comment: but that its not free. i know that its one of the bests on the market, but equally expensive :P. tnx anyway